# Node js вывод 16-ного кода

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Передаю на страницу текст:

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("main/index", {
     title: 'Drak'thul'
});
```

Но выводит это:

```
Drak&#39;thul
```

EJS шаблон имеет вид:

```
<%= title %>
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Наверно этот модуль надо использовать https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities

Comment: `title: 'Drak\'thul'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно выводить переменную в шаблоне ejs не так:

```
<%= title %>     // Drak&#39;thul
```

А так:

```
<%- title %>     // Drak'thul
```

Answer (score 1):

```
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  res.render("main/index", {
     title: "Drak'thul"
});
```